# Bake hue and saturation into image and maintain transparency

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'd like to bake hue and saturation information directly into an image. This is my current setup that gives desired color values:

[image]

If I merge group into a single layer I lose all the information provided in `Hue/Saturation`

[image]

What should I do to maintain the color information in the highlight when I merge group?

Anytime merge group, layers or flatten operation is done without the black background enabled (Layer 8), the newly merged/flattened image loses hue color information. If the black bakcground is enabled, color is preserved.

Merging With black bacground is successful
[image: Merging With black bacground]

Merging with transparent background. Hue color information is lost.
[image]

My goal is to come up with transparent image of phone case and highlight, so I can overlay it on top.

Answer (score 2):

Simply **Flatten** the image - Layer Panel Menu > Flatten image.

Another option is to Merge Visible -- Create a new blank layer above everything, and highlight it, choose Merge Visible form the layer panel menu. This will basically flatten the image while *not* creating a "background" layer.

**What I generally use...**

If you wish to keep layers in tact and merge, hold down the **Option/Alt** key when you select Merge Visible. This will combine all visible layers to your new blank layer and keep other layers as they are.

[image]

All layers visible except the white screen.... I created a new layer... merged visible (with Option held down), and then copied the layer mask to the new layer.

Merging Visible of *only* the frame art and adjustments...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for stopping by. Unfortunately, none of the suggestions preserve the color in the highlight. Anytime I merge, flatten layers without the black background layer at the bottom enabled, I lose the color information. If I enable the black background layer, and then perform the merge or flatten, color is preserved. Unfortunately I need a transparent image.

Comment: I think this might something to do with hue and saturation being an adjustment layer

Comment: Merge visible *should* merge layers to exactly what you see. I'm afraid if that's not working it may take direct file examination, which would be kind of off topic. I've never seen merge visible fail.. with or without adjustment layers in play.

Comment: Take a look: https://ufile.io/0x2li. I think hue and saturation has some unexpected behaviour when operated on semi transparent pixels. On black bakcground, of look great, on white.. hue information is lost

Comment: See updated answer @arraysareslow It seems to work as I expect. Are you trying to eliminate the black? That'll never work. There *has* to be some hue/saturation present for any adjustment to those to work.

Comment: Ohh, so the problems that I have are just because my highlight is white+transparent without any blacks? What do you recommend if I wanted to change the color of the phone front (side pieces are controlled by different `hue and saturation` ) and semi transparent glare (https://imgur.com/a/KviCNaT)? I already have a mask for just the front part of the phone.

Comment: Well, if you look at my merged image above of the frame, you can se the white highlight is there (faintly). It'll only be really visible when there's something, other than white, under it. If you *also* want a shadow for the screen area, you'll have to create that separately.

Comment: yes, the white highlight is there, but it is just white. This is my problem all along. It is only white. I used hue so that it had blue also.. but that only works if the background is not transparent. The highlight needs to have some color information while maintaining transparency. What do you recommend that I do?

Comment: Well, if you want blue there, you need to create blue. You can't "adjust" white really. You should be able to create a blue band of pixels and blur/mask/lower transparency for it as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

1. set the visibility on only for layers you want to merge. Hide all others
2. Press `Ctrl + Alt + Shift + E`
3. Voila !

Edit: Command + Option + E (Mac)